# Extract letters (some numbers) and under scores from a character string

Tags: regex, r, string, character, gsub

I have a bunch of charter strings of various lengths that contain numbers and letters.  All charter strings end with an `_` followed with a number (e.g. _30, _100, _500, or _1000).

The `String` object below contains a few examples.

```
Strings <- c("DET37_30", "DET37_500",  "Ele_100",  "Ele_1000", "NDVI_MeanMax_100", "RadWint_30", "RadWint_500", "Slope_100")
```

For each column name, I want to select all the numbers, letters, and `_` prior to the final `_number`

For example `DET37_30` and `DET_500` would result in `DET37`, and `Ele_100` and `Ele_1000` would result in Ele.

In other words, I want all values before the ending `_30`, `_100`, `_500`, or `_1000`.

Comment: @Richard Scriven done, where did your answer go it was nice :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
gsub("(.*)_[0-9]*","\\1",Strings)
```

It replaces the whole string by whatever is before the underscore.

Answer (score 0):

```
sub("_\\d+$", "", Strings)
#[1] "DET37"        "DET37"        "Ele"          "Ele"          "NDVI_MeanMax" "RadWint"     
#[7] "RadWint"      "Slope"
```

This regex matches an underscore followed by one or more digits, and it uses the `$` anchor to allow only matches at the end of the line.